# Is there a visible difference between 60 FPS vs 120 FPS in gaming?

Tags: hardware

Is there a visible difference between 60 FPS vs 120 FPS? I am going under the assumption that the monitor is your standard 60 Hz monitor.  I've heard arguments that you would want a higher FPS for first-person shooter games then 60 FPS. I am looking for a good answer that actually has some technical merit behind if possible.

Comment: A 60 Hz monitor showing a 120 FPS (average) source may show less tearing with V-sync off as the FPS fluctuates, and smoother gameplay with V-sync on (since it's jumping between 120 and 60 FPS rather than 60 FPS and 30 FPS as it fluctuates), but I can't think of much other advantage to frames that you can't actually see. The benefit would all be of the interpolation sort like the V-sync issue.

Comment: ...there is no point in drawing frames to the frame-buffer faster than the monitor can display them.  The extra frames will literally never be seen by you.

Comment: Any reasons for down-votes? This is one of the most common statements I see from the Counter Strike community that you want the highest frame rate possible. I understand the that you drawing frames faster then the monitor can display. I am trying to understand if there is any validity of those statements.

Comment: It's a good question, I'm not sure why it's downvoted.

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/can-the-human-eye-distinguish-frame-rates-above-60-hz

Comment: @Halfwarr Including the reason for why you're asking in the original post (instead of a comment) is always a good idea. It can avoid a lot of downvotes.

Comment: @Resorath: He's not even talking about that; he's asking if having the game run at 120fps **when the monitor is still refreshing at 60Hz** would show any improvement vs 60fps.  To which the answer is no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compare a stable 60FPS with a stable 120 FPS you should see no difference at all.

A 60Hz monitor refreshes the screen 60 times a second, so at 60 fps there is a frame drawn every time the screen refreshes, and at 120 fps there is a frame drawn every time the screen refreshes and once in between refreshes, so it's not shown on the screen but does get drawn.

In the case of fluctuation both could get some tearing if the frame is half drawn on the screen refresh.

People want certain frame rate locks in certain games because of the game engine bugs that manifest at that frame rate.

If you can get a constant 60fps (ironed out with vsync to prevent screen tearing when it goes over 60) you should be good to go, on a 60 hz monitor you won't be able to see the extra frames unless they manifest as screen tearing.